# Calculate Distance : How can we calculate distance between two SKCoordinate Points

Tags: android, skobbler-maps

Using the Skobbler map SDK, how can we calculate distance between two SKCoordinate Points. 
Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the SKGeoUtils class, you will find the method `calculateAirDistanceBetweenCoordinates(SKCoordinate pointA, SKCoordinate pointB)`

Which should do what you are looking for.

Link to the doc.
https://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/util/SKGeoUtils.html

Comment: Ya this is one method to find but what are the methods they used to calculate distance in demo project???